# Iteration speed of unordered_set vs vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have an application where I need to store various subsets of different customers. *The order of the customers in the container does not matter*.

Since the order does not matter, I was hoping that storing and iterating through this set of customers would be faster on an `std::unordered_set<int>` as compared to `std::vector<int>`.

[CPPREference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/), however, states:

> unordered_set containers are faster than set containers to access individual elements by their key, although they are generally less efficient for range iteration through a subset of their elements.

To test this out, I evaluated the time it takes to iterate through `std::unoredered_set` and `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>

static const int NoElements = 100000000;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> VecofElems;
    VecofElems.reserve(NoElements);

    std::unordered_set<int> SetofElems;
    SetofElems.reserve(NoElements);

    for (int i = 0; i < NoElements; i++)
        VecofElems.push_back(i); 
    for (int i = 0; i < NoElements; i++)
        SetofElems.insert(i);

    auto VecIterStartTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long vec_cumulative_sum = 0;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator viter = VecofElems.begin(); viter != VecofElems.end(); ++viter)
        vec_cumulative_sum += *viter;
    auto VecIterEndTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> VecTime = VecIterEndTime - VecIterStartTime;
    
    auto SetIterStartTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long set_cumulative_sum = 0;
    for (std::unordered_set<int>::const_iterator uositer = SetofElems.begin(); uositer != SetofElems.end(); ++uositer) {
        set_cumulative_sum += *uositer;
    }
    auto SetIterEndTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> SetTime = SetIterEndTime - SetIterStartTime;

    printf("Vector Sum %ld, Size %ld, Time Taken %f\n", vec_cumulative_sum, VecofElems.size(), VecTime);
    printf("Set Sum %ld, Size %ld, Time Taken %f\n", set_cumulative_sum, SetofElems.size(), SetTime);

    getchar();
}
```

The output on my machine, when the above is compiled in Release Mode of MSVC compiler is:

```
Vector Sum 887459712, Size 100000000, Time Taken 51.340000
Set Sum 887459712, Size 100000000, Time Taken 4772.139100
```

indicating that iterating through a `vector` is many orders of magnitude faster than an `unordered_set`.

In my application, since the order of the elements in a container do not matter, and since an `std::vector` preserves order (unnecessarily in this case), is there any other container that can be faster than even `std::vector` in iterating through various elements of the container?

Comment: A vector stores its elements in contiguous memory, that is the major difference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is there a way to have contiguous memory storage, and not have order preserved? Wouldn't such a container, if one is available, be even faster since the requirement of order preservation would not hold it back?

Comment: There are third-party map containers that attempt to do that (store things in contiguous memory).  You won't be able to find it in the standard map and associative containers, however.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see. Do you have any suggestion of a 3rd party container that does that?

Comment: It's really off-topic to discuss or recommend other libraries.  But you could [start here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Comment: @Mat Suppose there is a costly function that returns a double to evaluate on a set where the order does not matter -- `f(S)`. One could have some sort of a map<Set, double> or memoization in place to prevent repeated costly calculations on the same set represented by two different vectors. One could check whether the current vector to evaluate has already been evaluated before by creating a new set out of this vector. This operation could become quite repetitive.

Comment: `std::vector` is fast also because doesn't care about ordering. It preserves the insertion order because it does exactly nothing about it. If you find a dynamic container faster than `std::vector` you should definitely send a TS to the standard committee to add it in the STL

Comment: Are there specific hard performance limits than your application is struggling to meet? If this is not the case, just don't worry about performance. Worry about correctness, simplicity and maintainability first.

Comment: @Tryer That logic is flawed. There is no overhead for preserving order if things are just thrown in whatever order they come and never changed. The important difference here is how elements are stored and how lookup into the container works.

Comment: For something faster, you can go with `std::array` since it will be allocated on the stack. Do note you probably won't have enough stack to allocate 100000000 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::vector is the fastest STL container for linear iterations like in your scenario. This is simply because memory is contiguously allocated and therefore can benefit of caching mechanisms. A vector iterator just increments a pointer internally.

You might improve performance further by trying to use a smaller type than `int` when possible.

In your case I think parallelization/SIMD would give largest performance boost for reduction. This might be achieved by auto vectorization (check project compiler settings).

You could also try OMP to do this like this (not tested)

```
size_t end = VecofElems.size();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(vec_cumulative_sum ) reduction(+: vec_cumulative_sum )
for (size_t i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
    vec_cumulative_sum += VecofElems[i];
}
```

This would run multiple threads in parallel. Therefore it's important to declare `vec_cumulative_sum` as being shared amongst the threads.

`std::for_each` provides some simple way to make use of parallelism including vectorization. This allows to simply use any STL container like std::vector (and any other container providing iterators) like this

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par, VecofElems.begin(), VecofElems.end(), 
    , []() {
        // have some fun using a lambda, or function
    }
}
```